# What is the difference between using pip3 vs pip when running python3 virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running python3 inside a virtualenv which I created as follows

```
==> python3 -m venv venv

==> source venv/bin/activate

==> python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr 25 2018, 14:23:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

My web-app has a requirements file with the python package dependencies

What is the difference between using pip3 vs pip to install the dependencies

i.e.

```
==> pip3 install -r requirements
```

vs

```
==> pip install -r requirements
```

Comment: `pip2` is python2 and `pip3` is python3. Use the `whereis pip` command to determine where the executables are located, but if you are in a python3 virtualenv, `pip` is most certainly equivelent to `pip3`.

Comment: That's what I thought but thanks for confirming!!

Comment: I added as an answer. If you feel it answered your question, I would appreciate an acceptance

Comment: Done. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pip2` is python2 and `pip3` is python3. Use the `whereis pip` command to determine where the executables are located, but if you are in a python3 virtualenv, `pip` is most certainly equivalent to `pip3`.